# Align google chart to right

Tags: php, html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTquB.jpg

here is a screenshot of my problem, there's 2 pie charts above each other, how do i make them go next to each other? I am using the google api for charts

Would this be a html or css edit? if so how would I go about changing where it is?

Im using SB admin 2 as a template, ive tried using  tabs but im either not using them correctly or they're just not having it

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div id="top5os" style="width: 700px; height: 300px; background:red;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div id="top5country" style="width: 700px; height: 300px; background:blue;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `flex`, and you can either `align-items` or `justify-content`

Answer (score 0):

use css like 
div.container{
    align: right;
    or
    float: right;
}
if neither of those work you can say
div.container{
     position: fixed;
     and 
     left: 900px;
}

Comment: `position:fixed` is not a good idea, you can either suggest `position:relative` and `left` or `position:absolute` and `right:0px` something like that.

Comment: Dhaval is correct, only use position fixed if you have to as a last resort.